# transfer variables between class A and B

Tags: php

How i can run method $this->ob->getVar() inside class B function C here ? I get no. Did i must transfer string to constructor ?

```
<?php 


class A{

  public $tabb = array('1'=>'one', '2'=>'two');
  public $index;

  public function setVar($v){

    $this->index = $v;

  }

  public function getVar(){

    return $this->index;

  }

  public function arr(){

    return $this->tabb;

  }

}


class B{

  public $tab;

  public function __construct($var){

    $this->ob=new A;

    $this->tab = $var;

  }

    public function C(){

     return $this->D($this->tab, $this->ob->getVar());

      }

  public function D($l, $j){

    if(is_array($l) && isset($j)){

      print 'yes';

  } else { 

    print 'no';

  }

  }

}

$obb = new A;
$obb->setVar('onetwo');
$k = $obb->arr();
$obbb = new B($k);
$obbb->C();


?>
```

Comment: Just call `$this->ob->getVar()` in that method. This code is perfectly valid

Comment: the same effect only have array transfer for constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, for the sake of convention your B class should declare a private variable of $obj, but that is not necessary in PHP.

Second, your B class is just creating a new instance of A in its constructor. So you have two different A classes. The once inside B never has its index property populated.

If you wanted to have the A object created outside the B object you'll have to pass it in like this:

```
$obbb = new B($k, $obb);
```

So now your new B constructor is something like this:

```
public function __construct($var, $someObject){

    if (!empty($someObject)) {
        $this->ob = $someObject;
    }
    else {
        $this->ob=new A;
    }

    $this->tab = $var;

}
```

Comment: thank i can use reference, inheritance here, getInstance method ?

Comment: this work, but still i transfer my variablees from constructor;)

Comment: You want to send your variables in your constructor. Otherwise you would need to use a global and that is not really good practice. Sometimes as a compromise you'll see a class refer to something in the $GLOBALS array, but that makes your class less transparent to another user of the class. By passing what you need in the constructor you explicitly define what that class needs, but using a global hides this from the outside requiring a user of the class to read the code in order to understand what $GLOBALS must be populated before using the class.